# I want to add GA code in header-view.js by checking NODE_ENV

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I want to add GA code on Production environment .
Currently I have dev , stage and prod environment.
I am using webpack configurations to create /Manage build on dev /prod environment.

I just wanted to know about how to add environment specific GA code in header file.
Can i use HtmlWebpackPlugin to load Google analytics id .

Answer (score 0):

You can read the value from environment variables in your webpack configuration and then use that in your header-view.js.

Sample webpack configuration:-

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': {
      'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.environ),
    }
  })
  ]
```

In you header-view.js you can check it as:-

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  //ga code 
}
```

While running webpack you can either set is environment variable or pass it directly in the command, like `environ=production webpack -p //for production`